# Android XMLPullParserException expected START_TAG

Tags: android, soap

The application prepares an Envelope with the following 1st string:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

When a call is being made, in response dump I see this 1st string:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

Attention: **https**

and system error:

```
expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <{https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}s:Envelope>
```

Looks like `XMLPullParser` cannot recognize the XML because of this `HTTPS`.

How can I change it?

Code to create an envelope:

```
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "XMLDataGet";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "https://website.com/_vti_bin/MY.APP/APPService.svc";
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IAPPService/XMLDataGet";

=========================

    try {

                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                request.addProperty("entity", "persona");
                request.addProperty("last_update_date", "20140101");
                request.addProperty("country", "UA");
                request.addProperty("user", "someuser");

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            Log.i(TAG, "Envelope to String: \n" + String.valueOf(envelope));
            Log.i(TAG, "request to String: \n" + String.valueOf(request));

                envelope.implicitTypes = true;
                envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
                envelope.dotNet = true;

                envelope.bodyOut = request;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed that by catching InputStream and replacing `https` with `http`